# send large json string via httpclient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am trying to send a large json string via httpclient, **the communication is fine**, i am able to send less than 15mb string but more than that is throwing the following errors :

```
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Broken pipe.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (32): Broken pipe
```

i think the server is closing the connection before completing the tranfert, note that everything is working fine if the string content is smaller.

client :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try {
                var files = new StringContent(GetData(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
                var result = client.PostAsync("Action/push", files).Result;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
                    UploadSize();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed.");

                Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Well, you have answered yourself: *"i think the server is closing the connection before completing the tranfer"*. A lot of servers do restrict the max POST size and if it's surpassed close the connection. So, the problem is not your code but the server, you need to configure it to accept requests larger than 15Mb.

Comment: yes, but i couldn't find how to configure the size or the wait time that's why i am asking.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that in two ways :

**1st solution :**

add `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>` to your <*security*> in **web.config** file

**2nd solution (MVC)** which i find much cleaner, add the following to your post method :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit] // or
        [RequestSizeLimit(50000000)] //50mb
        public IActionResult UploadFile([FromBody] Data data)
        { }
```

thanks to : https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/